# How to import function from other class in typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to import the other class(decided by name string,for example B) to the present class(named A).
function in class B needs to call function in class A.
I want to know to how to implement.

```js
// index.ts

function importAll(obj, src){
    for (var key in src) obj[key] = src[key];
    return obj;
};

 class A{
    function_a(){
        console.log("A_test");
    }

    call_function_b()
    {
        let classtype="./Bclass";
        // dynamicly import class B 
       let B = require(classtype);
       let object_b= new B(); 
       // want to import all function from class B to class A
       // like importAll(this, object_b);

    }
}

export let test =new A();
test.call_function_b();
```

```js
//file Bclass.ts
export class B{
    function_b() {
        console.log("B_test");
    }

    function_use_a()
    {
        // function in class B need to call function in class A
        this.function_a();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for `A extends B`.

The `extends` keyword is used in class declarations or class expressions to create a class which is a child of another class.

```js
class B {
  
  b_func() {
    console.log('b func');
  }
}

class A extends B {
  
  a_func() {
    console.log('a func');
  }
}


const a = new A();
a.b_func();
```

Comment: A will import different classes, B is just a example.